Frequency of Pendulum Outside the Small Angle Approximation
I understand that if one makes the small angle approximation, the angular frequency of, say, a pendulum, is easy to find as $\sqrt{k/m}$. Without making any approximations and sticking with the original equation $m\ddot \theta=-k\sin \theta$, we cannot analytically solve the system as we have an elliptic integral. However, I was wondering if it was possible to at least determine properties of the exact frequency of the oscillation of this system (e.g. is it rational, transcendental, etc.), or more generally: are there any significant statements we can make at all about the system that aren't based on numerical approximations?

Elliptic integral is an exact solution. It is just not in simple algebraic closed form. There are also systems exhibiting exactly the SHO behaviour, as long as you find some way for the potential to actually be $x^2$.

Does this answer your question? Solution to pendulum differential equation

transcendental or algebraic etc depends entirely on the coefficients, if $k=\pi^2$, the frequency is going to transcendental, maybe, and ofc, it depends on the definition of units. E.g., the km used to be such that 10,000 of them were from the poles to equator, by if new km's were the radius of Earth, then Bam: km' to feet is transcendental.
